# How to cancel request and return a timeout error if request takes more than a particular time in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, request-cancelling

I want to write an API in Nodejs which will return an error if the excution takes more than a particular time otherwise will proceed normally. How to do that??
Regards,
Abdul

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best general practice to timeout a function in promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936824/what-is-the-best-general-practice-to-timeout-a-function-in-promise)

Answer (score 0):

The node thread needs to co-operate by clearing everything that is running on the event loop and then it terminates naturally by returning. So just stop listening for requests, close handles etc. You can use `process._getActiveRequests` and `process._getActiveHandles` to see what is keeping the event loop alive.

You can also abruptly interrupt the node thread just by calling OS apis but this will leak a lot of garbage until you exit the process so you cannot start/restart node a lot of times before you need to exit the process anyway to free the leaked resources.