# Promise.allSettled() - Retry strategy for multiple async calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, es6-promise

TL;DR: I'm looking for a strategy or an example of handling an unknown amount of promise rejections and retrying them an `X` amount of time when using `Promise.allSettled()` for multiple async calls.

After reading this article: https://www.coreycleary.me/better-handling-of-rejections-using-promise-allsettled
I got pretty excited by this sentence:

> This is great because we can still load the user account info, and
> retry fetching the user activity later. (retries are outside the scope
> of this post, and there are multiple strategies for that)

However, when researching online I found absolutely none concrete examples, or even posts that deal with this issue directly.

Here is some example code:

```
  public async test() {
    try {
      console.log('trying..');
      const multiAsync = [this.somethingA(), this.somethingB(), this.somethingC()];
      const [a, b, c] = await Promise.allSettled(multiAsync);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('catch');
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Now lets say for the above code, both A and C failed, and I want to retry them, let's say- just one more time.
Even Though I have `a, b, c`, I only know which is `fullfilled:true` and which are not. but I don't know to link `a` back to `somethingA()` and `c` to `somethingC()` to retry only those 2 functions, and I definitely don't want to invoke `somethingB()` twice..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Promises do not keep any record of where they came from: Once you have a Promise, there's nothing that would allow you to retry its origin multiple times. As such, [common Promise retry patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38213668/1426891) accept the promise-returning function ("promise factory"), not just the Promise itself. **Wrapping each individual promise in a retry function like this before calling `all` or `allSettled` is the most practical solution**, since promises that fail quickly can try again immediately without waiting for the entire list like `allSettled` does.

```js
const multiAsync = [
  retry(() => this.somethingA(), 3),
  retry(() => this.somethingB(), 3),
  retry(() => this.somethingC(), 3),
];
const [a, b, c] = await Promise.allSettled(multiAsync);

// or

const [a, b, c] =
    await Promise.allSettled([/* functions */].map(x => retry(x, 3));
```

However, if you'd like to see how to use `Promise.allSettled` to do this directly, I have one here. My solution here doesn't respect timeouts, which you can add globally or individually [with a `Promise.race` implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30940189/1426891).

```js
/**
 * Resolves a series of promise factories, retrying if needed.
 *
 * @param {number} maxTryCount How many retries to perform.
 * @param {Array<() => Promise<any>>} promiseFactories Functions
 *     that return promises. These must be functions to enable retrying.
 * @return Corresponding Promise.allSettled values.
 */
async function allSettledWithRetry(maxTryCount, promiseFactories) {
  let results;
  for (let retry = 0; retry < maxTryCount; retry++) {
    let promiseArray;
    if (results) {
      // This is a retry; fold in results and new promises.
      promiseArray = results.map(
          (x, index) => x.status === "fulfilled"
            ? x.value
            : promiseFactories[index]())
    } else {
      // This is the first run; use promiseFactories only.
      promiseArray = promiseFactories.map(x => x());
    }
    results = await Promise.allSettled(promiseArray);
    // Avoid unnecessary loops, though they'd be inexpensive.
    if (results.every(x => x.status === "fulfilled")) {
      return results;
    }
  }
  return results;
}

/* test harness below */

function promiseFactory(label) {
  const succeeds = Math.random() > 0.5;
  console.log(`${label}: ${succeeds ? 'succeeds' : 'fails'}`);
  return succeeds
      ? Promise.resolve(label)
      : Promise.reject(new Error(`Error: ${label}`));
}

allSettledWithRetry(5, [
  () => promiseFactory("a"),
  () => promiseFactory("b"),
  () => promiseFactory("c"),
  () => promiseFactory("d"),
  () => promiseFactory("e"),
]).then(console.log);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jeff, what an amazing answer. Exactly the explanation I was looking for, and the related thread sent me in the right direction to find `utils-decorators` which I'll probably use.

Answer (score 0):

This worked well with me.

```
export const allSettledWithRetries = async (
  promises: Promise<FixMeLater>[],
  retries: number,
  waitBetweenRetries = 1000
): Promise<FixMeLater[]> => {
  const results = await Promise.allSettled(promises);

  const successResponses: FixMeLater[] = [];
  results.forEach((promiseResult) => {
    if (promiseResult.status === 'fulfilled') {
      successResponses.push(promiseResult.value);
    }
  });

  if (retries > 0 && successResponses.length !== promises.length) {
    const failedPromises: Promise<FixMeLater>[] = [];

    results.forEach((promiseResult, index) => {
      if (promiseResult.status === 'rejected') {
        failedPromises.push(promises[index]);
      }
    });

    logger.warn(`failed to run ${failedPromises.length} and will try again`);

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-promise-executor-return
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, waitBetweenRetries));

    const failedResults = await allSettledWithRetries(
      failedPromises,
      retries - 1
    );

    failedResults.forEach((promiseResult) => {
      if (promiseResult.status === 'fulfilled') {
        successResponses.push(promiseResult.value);
      }
    });
  }

  return successResponses;
};
```