# How to handle a Promise that is never resolve or rejected without using timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I am using TypeScript in Node.js. I have simplified my code to the following:

```
async function runPromise(promise: Promise<unknown>) {
    await promise
    console.log('done')
}

void runPromise(new Promise(() => {
    console.log('in promise')
}))
```

When I run this, I get the following output and then the process ends with a 0 exit status:

```
in promise
```

Because the Promise is never resolved or rejected, it never runs the `console.log('done')` line.

I would like to be able to handle cases where runPromise is called with a Promise that never resolves. Is there a way to have this throw an error rather than silently exit? I would like to avoid using some kind of timeout as I won't really know how long it should take.

---

I should have asked this originally, but why does Node.js shut down the process when there is an outstanding promise rather than hanging indefinitely? I see reference to the halting problem. I assumed Node.js would be aware of outstanding promises, but I see that must not be a valid assumption.

Also, I have corrected the code so the promise does resolve but it took quite a bit of time to debug, so I was just trying to improve my runPromise function to be more strict and fail with an error rather than silently shutting down. I would like to prevent such errors in the future.

Comment: I think it's necessary to have some kind of timeout value to determine when a Promise is considered **"stuck"** and should trigger an error.

Comment: _"Is there a way to have this throw an error rather than silently exit?"_ No, it's not possible. Let's say the promise waits for a server response or user event. How should the client know if this promise ever resolves?

Comment: This sounds like [the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: What about timing out the promise if it's unresolved after a period of time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936824/what-is-the-best-general-practice-to-timeout-a-function-in-promise

Comment: @InSync correct. It's the one.

Comment: No, this is not possible. Fix the code that creates the promise but never settles it.

Comment: "*Why does Node.js shut down the process when there is an outstanding promise rather than hanging indefinitely? I assumed Node.js would be aware of outstanding promises*" - node.js shuts down when there are no active asynchronous tasks (timeouts, network activity, listeners on open ports, file system accesses, etc) left. It does not track promise objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments: This is impossible.

There is no general algorithm to determine whether a `Promise` will settle or not, for the same reason there is no general algorithm to determine whether a program [will halt or not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

That said, either just [use a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30936824) or fix the source of that `Promise`.